# How to cut and join "wedges" of plywood to form a perfect circle

Tags: joinery, plywood, cutting, table-making

My wife wants a new dining room table -- a round one of about 4.5' in diameter.

I am constructing it out of rift sawn white oak. I will be using 3/4" ply for the table top (MDF core) and then laminate bending white oak around the edge (circumference), possibly with a strip of walnut in there as well.

My question has to do with the ply wood. In essence I want to create a pattern similar to this one:

[image]

As you can see, it appears to have 12 separate "wedges", with the grain running towards the center. I have searched the web to no avail as to how to create a table top like this. So my question:

**How do I go about cutting and assembling 12 different "wedges" of 3/4" ply into a perfect circle?**

Comment: What @mmathis said. Although you can do this by cutting segments and sticking them together it's much better if you don't have all that cutting and all those joints to worry about. Obviously this means you have to learn how to veneer but it's not that difficult ....probably easier than cutting the segments accurately! And you don't need to learn how to handle a new glue, you can use white PVA if your veneer isn't too thin.

Comment: That is, almost beyond a doubt, a veneered table. So do it that way, on a nice solid circle (or is this a pull-apart with leaves and two half-circles?) The only possible reason to cut wedges in anything but veneer is if you are having a solid-lumber-snob attack (I may, at times, resemble that viewpoint, but I think I got past the acute phase.) That would complicate construction as well, but there's be some reason to it. A mad, idealistic reason, but a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make the wedges out of plywood, but rather make them out of veneer. This allows you to have a solid tabletop, but still get the design you want.

There is a video series by [GuysWoodshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoNUw-hNkxU&list=PL__Cj5bOsaAPYcVFBFP2ZUpbFwPUWtK4G) (think this project was a viewer project on Matt Cremona's channel) showing almost exactly what you're trying to do.

[image: screenshot]

---

Screenshot taken from part 6 of his video series

Comment: Not sure if it's just here but the screenshot isn't showing for me.